# ReactJs TetrisApp next TETROMINOES display Solution

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I working on this Tetrisapp with hooks, I want to move one step ahead I want to add current TETROMINOES shape to side display
I found that shapes are generating through src > component > `<StyledCell type={type} color={TETROMINOES[type].color} />`
where type is creating a TETROMINOES, I want to add this to display so it can show current TETROMINOES 
here https://codesandbox.io/s/ruhew link for playground I found online.
I want to add a small display after start game button

any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some brainstorming and Googling at last I found the solution,
Please head to my Github repo https://github.com/NishantThapa/TetrisAppWithHooks 
Feel free to fork it accordingly. :)